# How can we display a bunch of images from a folder of them? (a deck of cards)

Tags: java

So in our class we have a project to make a game and we are making a card game.

We have a folder called cards that has a .jpg of all the cards in a deck as well as the backs

i can get image per image manually but thats lag and no one wants that

how could we call the images(each with a file name of the card value and suit)?

Comment: It's generally recommended to show the actual code you've tried. Gives us a bit more direction with file structure, names, how you're storing the images in memory currently, etc. Also demonstrates that you've attempted something, you're willing to learn, etc. :)

Answer (score 4):

Get all the images on loading of the game and store them in variables. Then when you need them, you call the variable programmatically without having to re-read the image in -- minimal lag. If this is a Swing GUI (you don't say), you could store them as ImageIcons and display the icons in JLabels.

The fine details of the solution will depend on the fine details of your problem, your file structure and your current code base.

Answer (score 3):

Establish some pattern for the filenames (e.g. card_{{SUIT}}{{VALUE}}.jpg). Then when you load, you'd have something along the lines of:

```
for each suit
    for each value
        load "card_" + suit + value + ".jpg"
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a learning exercise, I'd recommend just doing your best to find a solution that works.

However, if you want to go the extra mile, you can store the images as static in your card or deck class file so there's only one version of each image in memory. In terms of the best practice for categorizing the cards, I'd recommend giving the card class some enumerators. [Here's the oracle enumerators tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)